# get redis list slower than pushing into it when using redis as input of logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, redis, logstash

I have followed the instructions from the web below to build a log virualing system 
http://michael.bouvy.net/blog/en/2013/11/19/collect-visualize-your-logs-logstash-elasticsearch-redis-kibana/

Log in disk-->logstash-forwarder   ---------->      redis -->logstash-->elasticsearch

All things worked out until adding four servers to send their logs to my central log collecting server.

**The memory of redis server increased as time goes by and finally crashed when all memory has been consumed.**

I checked a period of time using redis-cli monitoring and found out the speed of rpushing to redis was much more faster than the speed of blpop from redis, which I think is the reason why the memory of redis server increased.

weblogic@MSAMGM01:~/logcenter/redis/bin$ ./redis-cli monitor > 1.txt

weblogic@MSAMGM01:~/logcenter/redis/bin$ grep blpop 1.txt | wc -l 
1159 
weblogic@MSAMGM01:~/logcenter/redis/bin$ grep rpush 1.txt | wc -l 
17123

Anybody have any idea or experience to solve this kind of problem?

BTW, the cpu of central server is quite low , which I confirm is not a root cause for this problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

According to the
[documentation for the Redis input](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-redis.html),
you should be able to set `threads` to the number of threads you want to use for
reading from Redis, perhaps you can increase this to pull more events from Redis
simultaneously?

Additionally, if logstash is too slow in the filtering pipeline, you can run
`bin/logstash -w <N>` where `<N>` is the number of filter workers to run
simultaneously.

Comment: I don't have any filters at indexer end.So I think the -w may not help. The config file listed below: 
 input {
redis {
       host => "127.0.0.1"
       data_type => "list"
       port => "6379"
       key => "logstash"
        threads => "16"
        batch_count=>"50"
        }
       }
output {
        elasticsearch {
       host => '127.0.0.1'
                        }
        }

Answer (score 0):

After some tries. I finnally found out the cause from elasticsearch log:

high disk water mark exceeded, and it would try to move the shards.

But I just have one node for testing, which I think is the cause for poor performance.

All things worked well aftering deleting some indices.